# How to export scm-manager-svn repo using ansible playbooks

Tags: svn, ansible

I need to export the remote svn repository under SCM manager to local server using ansible.
How to do that?

I have tried with **command** module :

```
 - command: svn export http://ip/scm/svn/dev/  /root/svn/ --username admin --password 1234 --force
```

it gets successful.

But while executing **subversion** module :

```
 - subversion:
      repo=svn+ssh://ip/scm/svn/dev # tried with repo=http://ip/scm/svn/dev
      export=True
      username=admin
      password=1234
      dest=/root/svn
```

it reports  error.

```
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "cmd": "/usr/bin/svn --non-interactive --trust-server-cert --no-auth-cache --username admin --password '********' export -r HEAD svn+ssh://ip/scm/svn/dev /root/svn",
    "failed": true,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "checkout": true,
            "dest": "/root/svn",
            "executable": null,
            "export": true,
            "force": false,
            "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
            "repo": "svn+ssh://ip/scm/svn/dev",
            "revision": "HEAD",
            "switch": true,
            "update": true,
            "username": "admin"
        }
    },
    "msg": "svn: E210002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn+ssh://ip/scm/svn/dev'\nsvn: E210002: To better debug SSH connection problems, remove the -q option from 'ssh' in the [tunnels] section of your Subversion configuration file.\nsvn: E210002: Network connection closed unexpectedly",
    "rc": 1,
    "stderr": "svn: E210002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn+ssh://ip/scm/svn/dev'\nsvn: E210002: To better debug SSH connection problems, remove the -q option from 'ssh' in the [tunnels] section of your Subversion configuration file.\nsvn: E210002: Network connection closed unexpectedly\n",
    "stderr_lines": [
        "svn: E210002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn+ssh://ip/scm/svn/dev'",
        "svn: E210002: To better debug SSH connection problems, remove the -q option from 'ssh' in the [tunnels] section of your Subversion configuration file.",
        "svn: E210002: Network connection closed unexpectedly"
    ],
    "stdout": "",
    "stdout_lines": []
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using `http` protocol with `command` module (which should go to port 80 on the SVN server) whereas the `subversion` module seems to be using `svn+ssh`. It might be that the SVN server is either not serving on port 22 (SSH) or there is a firewall that is blocking traffic to port 22.

A simple test would be to use `commmand` module with the `svn+ssh` URL. If it does not work, then the problem is almost certainly in establishing a connection to port 22.